# changed_when in a task containing loop should be true when any one of item task is changed

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to install plugins in jenkins using the following task.
It works fine as such but i want the task to restart jenkins when any new plugin is installed (i.e. when any of the individual item tasks is `changed`).

#### plugin.txt

```yaml
git
ssh
ruby
jquery
```

Now if I run the following task, the output is something like

```yaml
[Changed]
[OK]
[Changed]
[OK]
```

and finally the handler to restart jenkins is not called. Even if I have one `[Changed]` in output i want the handler to be called.
Here, [Changed] signifies that new plugin was installed and [OK] signifies that the plugin was already there.

I have tried finding logic for this task online but no luck till now.

```yaml
- name: Install Jenkins plugins.
  vars:
    jenkins_plugins: "{{ lookup('file', 'roles/jenkins-docker/templates/plugins.txt') }}"
  get_url:
    dest: "{{ jenkins_data_dir }}/plugins/{{ item | mandatory }}.jpi"
    url: "https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/latest/{{ item }}.hpi"
    owner: jenkins
    group: jenkins
    mode: 0644
    validate_certs: no
  register: result
#  changed_when:
#    - '"changed:" in result.stdout'
  loop: "{{ lookup('file', 'roles/jenkins-docker/templates/plugins.txt').splitlines() }}"
  notify: restart docker-compose-jenkins
  tags:
    - jenkins
    - jenkins-setup-plugins
```

Comment: There is for sure no `.stdout` returned from `get_url`; did you perhaps mean `changed_when: result.checksum_src != result.checksum_dest`?

Comment: @mdaniel, thanks a lot :) for looking into this. I have updated the question to give more clarity. I want the handler to be called when any new plugin is added. Hope that makes sense. And yeah, with `changed_when` in code it does not work as there is no stdout as you rightly said.

Comment: And have you already tried moving that `notify:` to its own task, which itself has `changed_when: result.results|select("changed")|length > 0` _(or similar, I don't have the exact syntax in front of me)_? Also, what is it doing instead of what you want -- is it skipping the notify task, or running the "restart docker-compose-jenkins" task but not producing the outcome you want?

Comment: ahh okay ... yeah that seems like a good idea. If I keep notifiy in a different task and run it only when `result.results|select("changed")|length > 0`. Its skipping the notifiy task. Expected outcome is to run notifiy even if we have one new plugin is added. Let me try the new approach you just suggested and update. Thanks a lot :) @mdaniel